# How can i get the index of the first and last char in string?

Tags: java, string

Assume the below string :

```
String value = "161207CAD140000,0";
```

how can i get the index of the first char and the index of the last char for the substring `CAD`
notice that the size of the substring may be changed from 2 ,3 or etc chars i want the solution to be dynamic.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and where it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `String.indexOf(String str)` function which will return starting indexof the "CAD". Then add one less then the length of String to find in the returned value, that will be your last character index of "CAD".

Something like this:

```
String value = "161207CAD140000,0";
String str = "CAD";
String datePart = value.substring(0, value.indexOf(str)); // for finding the date part
String amountStr = value.substring(value.indexOf(str) + str.length()); //for finding the amount part
System.out.println(datePart +"  "+amountStr);`
```

Now suppose the String "CAD" is dynamic and you don't know what value it will have, in that case its better to use regex. Please see below code snippet:

```
String value = "161207CAD140000,0";
String patt = "[\\d,]+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patt);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

while(matcher.find()){

    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

If any question let me know in comments. Hope it helps.

Comment: the string is not static and the searchString may be consist of two , three or etc chars. i want the solution to be dynamic

Comment: @Mohamed just look at it now it will help.

Comment: Okay then tell me in what form you have the value. Post your code or explain in comment.

Comment: the value string is what the user is expected to enter in the input field so i have to take this string and split it into three parts , Date = 161207 , currency = CAD , Amount = 140000,00 so the problem is that i need only the first and last index of the Currency which it will be the key to the other two strings .. got it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130510/discussion-between-sachinsarawgi-and-mohamed-nagy).

Answer (score 3):

This would do the job for any string.

```
String value = "161207CAD140000,0";
String searchedString = "CAD"
int firstIndex = value.indexOf(searchedString);
int lastCharIndex = firstIndex + searchedString.length();
```

Comment: the string is not static and the searchString may be consist of two , three or etc chars. i want the solution to be dynamic

Comment: @knaos For finding length of a String we use length() which is a function not a variable. Look at my answer.

Comment: @knaos your code will not compile only. Please check.

Comment: Editted and revised it. @MohamedNagy, this is a dynamic solution, you can use whatever string you want. Just place it in the searchedString variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are methods in the String class for such requirements. You can use the indexOf and lastIndexOf methods to get the positions. e.g

```
int index = value.indexOf("C"); //This returns 6
int lastIndex = value.lastIndexOf("D"); //this returns 8
```